# Does Java Swing limit how many items it will draw?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I'm writing a recursive method in Java that creates essentially creates a circle tree. It draws a circle at the top and center and then the method gets called again and creates the circles one level lower on the y axis and half way to the left and right of the new circle. I was successful but only for a certain number of objects to be drawn [This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUMBO.png)

```
public void test(Graphics g, int y, int num, double instance) {
        if(num<50) {

            int r = 20;

            for(int i=1;i<=instance;i++) {

                if(i%2==1) {
                    g.fillOval(getWidth() * i / num, y, r, r);
                }
            }
            if(instance==1){
                instance= 2* instance;
            }
            test(g, y + 20, num * 2, Math.pow(instance,2.0));
        }
```

Everything works perfectly until I try to increase the number in "if(num<50)" to exactly "if(num<65)". When I change that the JFrame appears but now it is empty and it seems like the program is frozen. I want to increase that so that I can fill the Jframe with the circle tree. Why is it doing that? Looking forward to your response! Thank you!

Comment: Profile it and see what your memory is doing.  I doubt very much that there's an arbitrary limit built into Swing.  It's something you're doing.

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I don't know why I choose to use Math power when I only had to use *2 and that fixed the whole program.